# How can I access the Internet through ssh tunnel to flutter app on an Android device?

Tags: android, flutter, ssh, tunnel

I had a question about connecting app flutter to ubuntu server through ssh tunnel, how can I establish user internet through this tunnel?

My connection to Ubuntu server is done through the ssh2 package in Flutter, session connection is success